# SQL Defining Weeks From Days

Tags: sql, date, week-number

I'm trying to summarize data in a table by weeks over the past 10 months. The only field in the table lists days in the format DD-MM-YY. Is there a simple way to group these data by weeks?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried till now

Comment: Date and string functions tend to be implementation-specific. Please tag your question with the appropriate DBMS. Also, provide sample table structures so we know the datatype you are using. Sample date and expected results would also be useful if you want a specific answer.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you? If yes, please vote up and/or mark as accepted, thx!

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this (tested with SQL Server):

Just paste this code into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(DateValue VARCHAR(8),OtherValue INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('30-09-15',10)
,('29-09-15',20)
,('28-09-14',30)
,('28-08-14',10)
,('27-08-14',10);


SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DateValue,3) AS ConvertedDate
        ,DATEPART(WK,CONVERT(DATETIME,DateValue,3)) AS WeekIndex
        ,OtherValue 
FROM @tbl

--And this is the way to use this for aggregates
;WITH MyData AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,DateValue,3) AS ConvertedDate
            ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,CONVERT(DATETIME,DateValue,3)) AS WeekIndex
            ,OtherValue 
    FROM @tbl   
)
SELECT WeekIndex,SUM(OtherValue)
FROM MyData
GROUP BY WeekIndex
```